# (Access 2010) Don't INSERT data unless foreign key exsist

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I'm trying to add some data which has a foreign key to another table( Each topic has a Thread, which is a foreign key) but the problem is, it allows me to insert anything when running INSERT INTO.

Is there anyway to validate it in MS Access 2010 to only allow INSERT INTO if the foreign key exists?

Cheers,

Comment: Have you set up relationships?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you are creating a query and the results will be inserted into the table.  So the answer to your question to have the query only return results where the foreign key exists.  So if you're trying to add to table Topic from table NewData, then you could make a view (a query in Access terms) that has a list of legitimate Foreign Keys, and then join NewData to ListOfKeys to restrict the query results to only those with good foreign keys.